# how to change file & product version of a exe file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, version, exe

I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. I have to change the version of my exe file. Please tell me how to do it, either by my C# code, or by batch file.

Comment: change the AssemblyFileVersion in your AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: So you just want to update the version normally? It sounded like you were asking how to modify the version of an already-compiled exe.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Somewhere in your code (favorably in `AssemblyInfo.cs` in the `Properties` folder of your project), put this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Also possible is the file version attribute:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Make sure that you only have one instance of `AssemblyVersion` and/or `AssemblyFileVersion` attributes in a single assembly - everything else won't compile.

Comment: @Reubz i meant to say that two instances of the same attribute won't compile

Comment: Be sure to refrence System.Reflection

Answer (score 16):

You can change the Exe Version through an Assembly file. There are 2 options:

1st option is is to edit the assembly file:

```
 [assembly: AssemblyTitle("TApplciation Name")]
    [assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyProduct("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2015")]
    [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.8.3")]
    [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("5.8.3")]
```

2nd option is through project Property. Go To Project Property and click on the button which is circled:
[image]

[image: Change Application Details]